# How to avoid Invalid snapshot time error in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to merge into one BQ target table from a source view. I am not using BQ legacy SQL.

While doing so I am getting error, `Invalid snapshot time t1 for table view1, Cannot read before t2`.

What does this Invalid Snapshot time error signify in BQ ? Also, how can I overcome that ?

Thanks
Sant

Comment: what is your full query?

Comment: @Pentium10, added queries below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pentium10,

As per log, there 2 separate jobs running at 10:36:32 and 10:36:52 , both trying to merge on same target T1 from same source VW1 but for different time ranges.
The merge queries are given below.

```
merge into tb1 t using (select * 
    from vw1 where 
    (startTime >= timestamp_millis(1606811400000) and startTime < timestamp_millis(1606813200000))) u 
on (coalesce(t.startTime, timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) = coalesce(u.startTime, timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) 
and coalesce(t.vendor, 'NULL') = coalesce(u.vendor, 'NULL') and coalesce(t.operator, 'NULL') = coalesce(u.operator, 'NULL') 
and coalesce(t.service_status, 'NULL') = coalesce(u.service_status, 'NULL') and coalesce(t.node, 'NULL') = coalesce(u.node, 'NULL') 
and ( t.startTime >= timestamp_millis(1606811400000) and t.startTime < timestamp_millis(1606813200000))) 
    when matched then update set 
    x = x1,y = y1,z = z1
    when not matched then insert 
    (x,y,z) values(x2,y2,z2) ;

merge into tb1 t using (select * 
from vw1 where 
(startTime >= timestamp_millis(1606812300000) and startTime < timestamp_millis(1606814100000))) u 
on (coalesce(t.startTime, timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) = coalesce(u.startTime, timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00')) 
and coalesce(t.vendor, 'NULL') = coalesce(u.vendor, 'NULL') and coalesce(t.operator, 'NULL') = coalesce(u.operator, 'NULL') 
and coalesce(t.service_status, 'NULL') = coalesce(u.service_status, 'NULL') and coalesce(t.node, 'NULL') = coalesce(u.node, 'NULL') 
and ( t.startTime >= timestamp_millis(1606812300000) and t.startTime < timestamp_millis(1606814100000))) 
when matched then update set 
x = x1,y = y1,z = z1
when not matched then insert 
(x,y,z) values(x2,y2,z2) ;
```

Thanks
Sant